# Percent format in SAS

Tags: sas, format

I am trying to understand the working of percent format in SAS.

```
data a;
a=put(1.1,percent4.);
run;
```

O/P:-
**%
I am expecting the output to return 110%.

I get the expected result when I use the following code:-

```
data a;
a=put(1.1,percent6.);
run;
```

Can anyone explain why I didn't get the expected result as the width of the o/p is 4 which shall be fulfilled by percent4. ?

Answer (score 3):

> From the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=p0c7jsl3orer8fn14dll459ifzmm.htm&docsetVersion=3.2&locale=en): The width of the output field must account for the percent sign (% )
>   and parentheses for negative numbers, whether the number is negative
>   or positive.

So for a percent value you always need 3 + w (the width) you would like displayed. In your case, you have 3, so 3+3 = minimum 6 to have it displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
data a;
     ab=put(1.100,percent6.2);
run;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how and why this answer the question